# How to change the border width of a tikz pie chart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I have the following pie chart and I would like to decrease the width of the black border line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny] 
\pie[radius=1.2,rotate=0,color={blue, red, yellow, green}]  
 {40/foo0, 51/foo1, 6/foo2, 3/foo3} 
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\centering
\caption{foo foo foo}
\label{fig:foo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried the following solution

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{pgf-pie} 
  \begin{document}

  \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.4\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
      \pie[
        radius=1.2,
        rotate=0,
        color={blue, red, yellow, green},
        style={border=1pt}
      ]{
        40/foo0,
        51/foo1,
        6/foo2,
        3/foo3
      }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \caption{foo foo foo}
  \label{fig:foo}
  \end{figure}

  \end{document}
```

It does the needed job, but I get the following error

*Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/border=1pt' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.*

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: So, is that with the `pgf-pie` package ?  An MWE starting from `\documentclass[...]{...}` to `\end{document}` would be much appreciated !

Comment: @ParthaD. Yes it is. The question is updated with the requested lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `tikzlibrarypie.code` file, we have, line 238 `style={thick}`. *(default parameters)*

By replacing in your code `style={border=1pt}` by `style =thin` or `style =very thin`, we may get what you want.

Answer (score 3):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The line width can be changed with the key `line width` in the settings of the key `slices style`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\wheelchart[
  counterclockwise,
  pie,
  slices style={
    fill=\WCvarB,
    draw=black,
    line width=0.5pt
  },
  start angle=0,
  wheel data=\WCperc
]{%
  40/blue/foo0,
  51/red/foo1,
  6/yellow/foo2,
  3/green/foo3%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One (not-so-scientific) way could be to scale the `tikzpicture` up to say 4 times including the text, and then use `\scalebox{0.25}` to scale it down again to the original size.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}

\newcommand{\piechart}{%
      \pie[
        radius=1.2,
        rotate=0,
        color={blue, red, yellow, green},
        % style={border=1pt}
      ]{
        40/foo0,
        51/foo1,
        6/foo2,
        3/foo3
      }
}
 
\begin{document}
 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \piechart
\end{tikzpicture}

\scalebox{0.25}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, 
   every node/.style={scale=4}]
    \piechart
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
 
\end{document}
```

which, apparently works --

[image: pie-chart with thick and thin lines]